# tvOS and hierarchical UITableView

Tags: uitableview, tvos, hierarchical

The tvOS Settings app has a large hierarchical UITableView. Items that go deeper have a ">".

What is the best way to do this? Are they reloading the table completely? It looks like they are sliding one view out for another. I am not using a storyboard so how can I accomplish this?

Note that my app actually does have a storyboard, but this UITableView needs to happen in a view that takes up less than the full screen and is controlled by its own ViewController... like preferences window.

Has anyone seen example code of a "deep" UITableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're using a `UINavigationController`, which is what causes that "sliding" effect.

Comment: That makes sense. Have you seen if there an example project that shows how this works? I guess I would need multiple `UIViewController` classes, one for each "page" of the hierarchical UITableView.